# Compiling Typescript code and loading the compiled JS

Tags: typescript

I generate Typescript code dynamically and save to disk to compile it with the TypeScript compiler. After compiling the source I need to dynamically load the resulting Javascript file and create an instance of the class defined in the JS.

This line:

```
let generated: any = require(`${__dirname}/generated/newFile.js`);
```

gives me back:

```
{ sampleClass: [Function: sampleClass] }
```

So how do I instantiate an object from this class?

Comment: `new generated.sampleClass()` ?

Comment: Funny I never tried that :-) Thanks!